# remove search box from users admin panel in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, search, wp-admin

i'm trying to remove search box in backend users.php to create my own search filter i used css `.user-search-input{display:none;}` but the value still running when using my own filter, is there anyway to remove this search box from functions.php

Comment: try p.search-box {display:none;visibility:hidden;}

Comment: hey thank you , but that box has input with value so what matter i do with css will not pass the value so need to remove it complitly